# Getting file-name of image-url MVC Core

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to store an image-url in by database. I am working with MVC Core and Entity Framework. More specifically I cannot get file.GetFileName to work. Please help!

Here is the Model:

```
  public class Product
{
   [Key]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter an product name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please specify a category")]
    public string Category { get; set; }

    public string SubCategory { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required
    (ErrorMessage = "Please enter a positive price")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    public string ImageSourceFileName { get; set; }

    public string ImageContentType { get; set; }

}
```

Here is the Controller that I am trying to work with:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> 
    Create([Bin("ProductID,Name,Category,SubCategory,Description,
    Price,ImageUrl,ImageSourceFileName,ImageContentType")] Product product)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Check if the request object has at least a file in it
            if (HttpContext.Request.Form.Files[0] != null)
            {
                // get the file into an IFormFile object
                var file = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files[0];

              var path = Path.Combine(
                   Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot",
                   file.getFileName());

                using (var fileStream = new FileStream
               (path, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                }
            }

            _context.Add(product);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(product);
        }
```

Comment: What is `getFileName()`? - `IFormFile` contains a property named `FileName` that contains the name of the file

Comment: What shall I write there instead? I want the filename which is contained in the wwwroot-folder.

Comment: What do you mean _which is contained in the wwwroot-folder_?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? Your creating a `FileStream` but doing nothing with it (I assume you want to assign it to the `byte[] Image` property? And what does your `var path = ...` code have to do with anything if your saving the image to the database?

Comment: I have now changed the product model so it contains a string ImageUrl instead of a byte Image. I do not want to save the whole image in the database - only the url. It will make the website slow.

Comment: Refer [this article](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/288/uploading-files-with-asp-net-core-1-0-mvc) for an example

Comment: Then store the file inside the `wwwroot` directory and store the file name (not the full url) in your table. when you have to render the image later, you can always build the relative url using this file name and use that as the image `src`